# bigcommerce hide a custom address field

Tags: bigcommerce

I want to hide one of the fields created in Advanced Settings > Account Setup Form (Address Fields) during the Shipping and Billing steps of optimized one-page checkout.

I can the field names/values using this api, but no ID.

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/customer-subscribers/v3-customers-api/customer-form-fields/customerformfieldsget

`https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{{store-hash}}/v3/customers/form-field-values?customer_id=1`

gives me this output

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Sales Agent",
            "customer_id": 1,
            "value": "Unassigned Customer-web (9990)"
        }
    ]
}
```

When editing in the admin console, it's referred to as FormFieldID

[image]

When in the checkout, the markup for this field is contained inside of a custom element, `dynamic-form-field` with a very predictable `name` attribute.

What's the deal with this?

```html
<dynamic-form-field 
  ng-repeat="formField in checkoutAddressCtrl.formFields track by formField.name" 
  class="dynamic-form-field dynamic-form-field--field_41" 
  ng-attr-mirror="{{ formField.name === 'addressLine1' &amp;&amp; 
  checkoutAddressCtrl.hasAutocomplete() ?'google-autocomplete' : null }}" 
  name="field_41" 
  field="formField" 
  on-change="checkoutAddressCtrl.onFieldChange(value, formField.name)" 
  value="checkoutAddressCtrl.address[formField.name]" 
  mirror="">
```

Comment: Hi! can you expand a bit on what your problem is? are you trying to hide that html tag?

Comment: I want to hide one of the fields created in Advanced Settings > Account Setup Form (Address Fields) during the Shipping and Billing steps of optimized one-page checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some css?

```css
[name="field_41"] { 
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: `field_41` will change between my dev, test and prod store instance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe from memory you can add a css class for the custom field in the Big Commerce control panel. So give it a class of, say, nodisplay, then add

```
.nodisplay {display: none}
```

to your store's css.

Comment: adding classes only affects the fields from Blueprint template. The class field doesn't affect a Stencil template.